# postgresql issue while installing Ambari on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

While trying to install Ambari 2.4 I am getting the below error.

```
root@ishanNode1:~# apt-get install ambari-server 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ambari-server : Depends: postgresql (>= 8.1) but it is not going to be       installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have installed postgresql as it was not installed by default in Ubuntu

```
root@ishanNode1:~# service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor  preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Fri 2018-02-16 00:01:58 IST; 16s ago
Process: 5847 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 5847 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 16 00:01:58 ishanNode1 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 16 00:01:58 ishanNode1 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: What version of Postgres do you have installed? Also, Ambari does not require Postgres, so that error is confusing to me

Comment: I have installed postgresql 9.4. If it does not require postgresql why its throwing the error

Comment: I would suggest you install a later version of Ambari, if possible, otherwise, see https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/15942/dependency-issue-when-running-yum-install-ambari-s.html